# Querying for users who have NOT completed a survey today and Receiving an error

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

I have a feature I am working on and I need my PostgreSQL db to return all the users that have not completed a survey today.

```
select distinct *
from users 
left join survey_results
on users.user_id = survey_results.user_id
where customer_id = '9000'
and survey_results.created_at < (DATE_PART('year', survey_results.created_at) = (SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
                                  AND DATE_PART('month', survey_results.created_at) = (SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) 
                                  AND DATE_PART('day', survey_results.created_at) = (SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)))
```

I am using a left join to join on my survey results table and filtering by customer_id and where the survey_results.created < today but I am using a date part and extract to get the date. If there is better way to do that chime in but that is what I have.

I am receiving this output when running my query instead of results.

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone < boolean
LINE 6: and survey_results.created_at < (DATE_PART('year', survey_re...
                                      ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 155
```

Comment: Consider using `NOT EXISTS`

Comment: That is an interesting idea do you mind expanding on it some. The only way I can tell if someone has not done there survey is if there user_id does not have a TIMESTAMP in the survey_results table and I am not sure how to work a NOT EXIST into my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using datepart, compare it with current_date -

```
select distinct *
from users 
left join survey_results
on users.user_id = survey_results.user_id
where customer_id = '9000'
and survey_results.created_at < CURRENT_DATE
```

If your survey_results.created_at column is timestamp, use date function to convert it to date then compare it to current_date -

```
select distinct *
from users 
left join survey_results
on users.user_id = survey_results.user_id
where customer_id = '9000'
and DATE(survey_results.created_at) < CURRENT_DATE
```

Comment: This removes my error and works now I am just worried my query isn't getting the users who haven't submitted today. But your solution worked Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Using `NOT EXISTS` and `today()` instead of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM users 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT
  FROM survey_results
  WHERE users.user_id = survey_results.user_id
  AND survey_results.created_at < today()
)
AND customer_id = '9000'
```

returns all people who have not completed a survey *before today*.

Comment: Im going to use NOW() instead of today. and this does get different results that my current query which is  `select distinct users.user_id, users.parent_id_1, users.parent_id_2, users.parent_id_3, users.parent_id_4, users.permitted
from users 
left join survey_results
on users.user_id = survey_results.user_id
where customer_id = '9000'
and DATE(survey_results.created_at) < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: After some testing my query is pulling correct results. Yours is def doing something though Im just not sure what

Comment: If you use `DATE() < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, you include results from today, because `DATE(this morning at 10 am) < NOW`. My query didn't have that, which might explain the difference. Another reason might be the timezone of `created_at`. It might be that last night at 11:55 is not included because it's stored as 01:55 (so today) in UTC

Comment: That could be it, but this query will run on schedule though so the 'current date' should be fine we only want to send email reminders to clients that have not surveyed before we run this process

Comment: In that case, completely drop the `created_at` constraint, since you don't care when it was created, just whether it exists